# INotifyPropertyChanged in a Core environment

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, porting

For years I have been using a WPF application and now I want to start implementing a Core project where I can store, well, my core classes. My goal is to keep away any and all WPF dependent classes (*Views, View Models, Resource Dictionaries*) from the Core project. The idea is that I can (potentially) create an ASP.NET or Xamarin or Unity project and use the core project in the back-end. But I came across a number of my classes that inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged`and I implement `RaisedPropertChanged(...)` in one or two *properties*.

My question is: is `INotifyPropertyChanged`limited to WPF? If it isn't, then, how is it it implemented in other environments like ASP.NET or Xamarin?

Comment: What would a property changed event signify in ASP.NET?

Comment: Why am I being downvoted? Why am I being chastised for wanting to grow as a developer? I'm sorry If my questions are basic. This really hurts because it discourages me from coming back here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My question is: is `INotifyPropertyChanged` limited to WPF?

No, it's not. It's part of .NET Standard 1.0 and available on all platforms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8